# taildwindcss config not applied in nuxt3 app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

I am still very much at the start of a new project using nuxt3. I installed tailwindcss for quick themeing and prototyping. I followed the basic setup on the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/tailwind/config#tailwindconfig) for the tailwindcss plugin for nuxt 3.

**The problem** is, that the background color for the welcome message is not applied (the CSS property also does not show up on the rendered HTML). When I change the CSS to something like this: `class="bg-green-200"`, then it works.

I could not find any similar issues, however I'm sure I can't be the first/only one stumbling over this. I appreciate any hints.

**Edit: ** The issue was the import syntax in the tailwind configuration file. Changing the import to the `require` syntax solved the issue.

My code is as follows:

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/robots',
    '@nuxtjs/color-mode',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
  ],
  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'de', name: 'Deutsch', iso: 'en-US', file: 'de.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'en', name: 'English', iso: 'de-CH', file: 'en.js'
      },
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'de',
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
    langDir: 'languages',
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: 'i18n_redirected',
      redirectOn: 'root',  // recommended
    },
  },
  buildModules: [],
  robots: {},
  tailwindcss: {
    configPath: 'tailwind.config.js',
    exposeConfig: false,
    injectPosition: 0,
  }
})
```

`tailwind.config.js`

```js
import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme'

export default {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: defaultTheme.colors.green
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`app.vue`

```html
<template>
    <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

`layouts/default.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <LayoutHeader/>
    <slot />
    <LayoutFooter/>
  </div>
</template>
```

`pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="bg-primary">Welcome to the homepage</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Give it a value of `primary: defaultTheme.colors.green.400` rather. Since green is an array of 10 values by default.

Comment: @kissu that sadly does not work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue being that `tailwind.config.css` is not a valid configuration file because we're using JS here, hence why [`npx tailwindcss init` is the recommended way](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs) to safely generate the configuration file (the config itself is a JS file, not a CSS one).

---

I have successfully installed it with the following `tailwind.config.js` file

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}",
    "./layouts/**/*.vue",
    "./pages/**/*.vue",
    "./plugins/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "./nuxt.config.{js,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.green
      }
    },
  },
}
```

---

Here is a reference to the documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#naming-your-colors

Here is a working [github repo](https://github.com/kissu/n3-tailwind/tree/main).

Comment: The config was a js file, sorry about that typo in the question. However the issue seemed to have been the import. It works since I change the import to the `require` syntax, without changing anything else.

Comment: @ClaudioBrasser yeah, there are some changes from time to time in the documentation of Tailwind. This is one of them I guess.